# How to use a PHP classes array as a name of a select tag HTML

Tags: php, html

i want to use what we call a struct in C but using PHP, I know Here they are called classes, but i need to use that array of classes for a select tag name, I am doing this

```
<?php

class info_subject{

   public $code_su;
   public $time_su;
   public $selecction_su;
}

$subjects= new info_subjects();

$i=0;

//THE DATABASE CONNECTION WORKS FINE, I IGNORED CODING ABOUT DATABASE BECAUSE THAT'S NOT THE  
//PROBLEM, JUST FOCUS IN THE STATEMENT OF THE ARRAYS IN THE TAGS NAMES PLEASE

while($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_NUM))//getting some stuff from postgrest
{

      echo "$line[0]";//I am printing this
      echo "$line[1]";//I am printing this

      //here i am creating selects in every loop with some options, and i want to save the 
      //result of the selection in the field code_su of the array of classes
      echo "<select name=$subjects[$i]->code_su>";
      echo "<option value='hola'>hola</option>";  

      //here i am creating checkbox in every loop, and i want to save the 
      //result of the checkbox in the field selection_su of the array of classes
      echo "<input type='checkbox' name=$subjects[$i]->selection_su>";

     $i++;
  }


?>
```

The problem is that it is not working, i think i am making a mistake with the statement in the names of the inputs and the selects, like i said before, i need a classes array.

Comment: try with: echo "<select name=\"".$asignaturas[$i]->codigo_as . "\">"; and "<input type='checkbox' name=\"".$asignaturas[$i]->seleccion_as."\">"

Comment: @oPi English only plz

Comment: @Justinas thats what im telling him about vars names ;)

Comment: @oPi yes, and I would add that "nifiga nieko nesuprantu ka parasiai".

Comment: @Justinas as i did for know what you wrote, "usa google". Anyway, i translate the comment

Comment: try using the var names in english for posting. Some people want them in that language

Comment: Men Your balls are as big as bull's balls, it worked

Comment: Now is in english, the variables names

Comment: @JoseRicardoCiterio haha ok ok. I add the comment as a response

Comment: @JoseRicardoCiterio please, if my answer is right accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that youre not adding the vars properly (nor the quotes). Try with:

```
echo "<select name=\"".$asignaturas[$i]->codigo_as . "\">";
```

and

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name=\"".$asignaturas[$i]->seleccion_as."\">"
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are echoing HTML wrong (missing `'`: `echo "<select name='{$asignaturas[$i]->codigo_as}'>";`

2) Your `$asignaturas` is not an array. It's only single class. Use it like this: `echo $asignaturas->coding_as;`

3) *(as side note)* By standarts, class names is CamelCases and it's name is same as file name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use the class itself as an array which can not be done.

Put in an constructor to define some of your variables here:

```
class info_asignatura{

   public $codigo_as;
   public $periodo_as;
   public $seleccion_as;

    function __construct(){
        $this->seleccion_as = array();
    }

}
```

The change this statement to:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name=$asignaturas->seleccion_as[$i]>";
```

Although, I fear this will not do the trick for you. Because every time this page is loaded, seleccion_as will be defined as an array when the class is constructed. This will overwrite anything previously declared.

What you will need to obtain your goal is to implement sessions to your code.